# Mouse not working in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, mouse

My friend has a system with Pentium 4 processor and Windows XP. Please help me figure out why the mouse is not working. The mouse cursor is showing even if the mouse is removed from the system.

It is a USB mouse. I plugged the mouse into all USB ports in the system, but it is shown as an unrecognised device. I searched in google and found to disable the Legacy USB device option in boot menu. I did it, but still the mouse won't work.

The next thing I found in google is to delete the USB controllers from the Device Manager and to restart the system. Still, the mouse doesn't work.

I plugged in another mouse to the system, which was used in my system. It too was not recognised by the system. What could be wrong?

Comment: Is the table a glass table? Also, is the mouse a laser/optical mouse?

Comment: Before you go deleting your USB controller do other USB devices work (ideally another USB mouse)?

Comment: @byachna Its a laser mouse. Whats glass table ?

Comment: @MatthewWilliams No other mouse didn't worked. But USB flash devices worked.

Comment: @Tom | Have you been through Microsoft comparability testing: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/compatibility/CompatCenter/Home